# Creating an Oracle User if it doesn't already exist

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, createuser

I am trying to create a script that will create users **if they do not already exist**.

```
CREATE USER "Kyle" PROFILE "DEFAULT" IDENTIFIED BY "password" ACCOUNT UNLOCK
WHERE NOT IN  //Also tried 'WHERE NOT EXISTS'
(
    SELECT username FROM all_users WHERE username = 'Kyle'
)
```

The following error is given:

> SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

I was able to do this in SQL Server 2008 by using:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(SELECT name FROM master.sys.server_principals
WHERE name = 'Kyle')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN Kyle WITH PASSWORD = 'temppassword' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON
END
```

Is there a similar way in Oracle to check if a user already exists before attempting to create a new user?

Comment: Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Before Oracle 23c, the `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax available in SQL Server is not available in Oracle.

In general, Oracle scripts simply execute the `CREATE` statement, and if the object already exist, you'll get an error indicating that, which you can ignore.  This is what all the standard Oracle deployment scripts do.

However, if you ***really*** want to check for existence, and only execute if object doesn't exist, thereby avoiding the error, you can code a `PL/SQL` block. Write a `SQL` that checks for user existence, and if it doesn't exist, use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to do `CREATE USER` from the `PL/SQL` block.

An example of such a PL/SQL block might be:

```
declare
userexist integer;
begin
  select count(*) into userexist from dba_users where username='SMITH';
  if (userexist = 0) then
    execute immediate 'create user smith identified by smith';
  end if;
end;
/
```

---

Since Oracle 23c, a user can be created like this:

```
create user if not exists smith identified by smith;
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to write a pl/sql block. See an example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0700__User-Privilege/CreateUserUtility.htm)

You can check if the user exists in the all_users table using some pl/sql code like:

```
SELECT count(*) INTO v_count_user
FROM all_users
WHERE username = 'Kyle'
```

and then use v_count_user in an IF condition to conditionally execute the create user statement.

Answer (score 3):

From the previous answers, it is clear that `if not exists` is not supported in Oracle. To clarify which error(s) are thrown by Oracle when attempting to create an already existing user (and as a bonus, when attempting to drop a non existing user):

```
drop user foo;
ORA-01918: user 'foo' does not exist

create user existing_user IDENTIFIED BY existing_user;
ORA-01920: user name 'existing_user' conflicts with another user or role name
```

The statements above were executed on Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to create the user in a PL/SQL block and catch the ORA-01920 error. That way, the block does not throw any errors when the user exists.

```
DECLARE
    sqlStatement varchar2(512);
    user_exists EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(user_exists, -1920);
BEGIN
    sqlStatement := 'CREATE USER "Kyle" ' ||
       'IDENTIFIED BY "password" ' ||
       'PROFILE "Default" ' ||
       'ACCOUNT UNLOCK';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlStatement;
    dbms_output.put_line('  OK: ' || sqlStatement);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN user_exists THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('WARN: ' || sqlStatement);
     dbms_output.put_line('Already exists');
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('FAIL: ' || sqlStatement);
     RAISE;
END;
/
```